# Facebook Like Box plug-in not working on web page test

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-social-plugins

I have just copied & pasted code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Here's a test page: http://net-gal.com/fbTest.html

I have viewed the page in Mac/Firefox & Safari plus pc/IE, and the plug-in puts lots of blank space but no Facebook feed.

How can I make my Facebook feed appear on the page?

under body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

in page to display:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/ginger.lindbergh" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

I added another test page that works using facebook developers page ID.
See test page: net-gal.com/fbTest2.html

The code was changed to: data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform"

So it appears the plug-in is working but not the link to my facebook page.  Is it my facebook security settings?  I checked & they seem fine.  I also replaced my text link with my numeric id link and results were the same;  there was no feed.  I added a new status update to my page but that didn't change it either. But I have eliminated the actual plug-in; it does work.

I am at a loss; can anyone help by telling me what I need to do to get this code to pull up my facebook like box?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Not everyone here is a native English speaker, so please try to write as clearly as you can. For example, don't leave out pronouns like "I". I've edited your question in an attempt to improve it without changing the meaning -- please review it to ensure that your meaning is preserved.

Answer (score 15):

I think the problem is with the code generator. I also faced the same problem. This was what I did to solve it:

Change the following line:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

To:

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

Answer (score 4):

You must have a **Facebook Fan Page** in order to use the Like Box Social Plugin. The Like Box plugin doesn't show your wall since your account is only a personal profile. Try with any fan page and it will work fine.

For example, replace: https://www.facebook.com/ginger.lindbergh

With: http://www.facebook.com/AxtraRD

Aditionally you could convert your Facebook Profile to a Fan Page. Following steps described here: https://www.facebook.com/help/116067818477568/

Comment: This helped, my FB page was not published, had the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is more simple than what everyone here saying. All you need to do is to upload your HTML file online and test online and that will work.

This will not work on your local machine. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You sooooo much.... i was testing it on my local machine which was the problem

Comment: Correct. This seems funny though. I wasted about 1 hour trying on my Local machine w/o any result.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to upload it anywhere. You can still test it locally with something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Answer (score 2):

Change line from this:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

To this:

```
js.src = "**http:**//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

And upload online! That solved my problem...

Answer (score -2):

IT DOES NOT WORK LOCALLY

you need to publish on a web server to test it